Issue with recaptcha site verify API SSL handshake
I have recaptcha used on my site on multiple places, signup & CSF. Till the 16th of July, all requests were normal and responded in quick time. But since 16th July we started experiencing delays in response from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
This delay is not happening for all the requests. Only 20% of requests are impacted. We started logging out all the information in the CURL response object and 80% of requests responded within 0.2 seconds whereas impacted requests took more than 1 second. Later we analyzed the delay in SSL handshake based on the logs.
We have Kubernetes set up and have multiple pods. We started identifying patterns but couldn't find any.

These requests do not originate from a single pod.
Not originated for customers residing in any single geo-location.
No recent changes on the server.
No recent changes on keys or secrets.

What could be wrong here?

In a recent analysis, I learned that all customers having delayed response have IPV6 and we are sending this IP as a remote_ip parameter to API.

Finally based on the analysis I found it was an issue with IPV6. In our code, we force CURL requests to resolve on IPV4. After that, we did not face any challenges or delays in response from Google.
curl -4
